# How to fix session problems on web host when header location change?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, redirect

When execute header("Location: new/location.php") command I got session problems.
On local host testing everything works just perfect, but if i send my project on web server hosting i got these errors:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk4/2008248/www/some-url.com/new/location.php:2) in /srv/disk4/2008248/www/some-url.com/new/location.php on line 7

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /srv/disk4/2008248/www/some-url.com/new/location.php:2) in /srv/disk4/2008248/www/some-url.com/new/location.php on line 7

, so my question is how to fix this problems and keep session values alive, so i can use that values in another redirected page?

Comment: You need to write session_start above headers(). As error says you already sent something beforee session start. Make Session start the very first line of your script, and leave no spaces before <?php tag

Comment: i write that, as i said on my localhost everything works like a charm

Comment: Post first 5 lines of location.php

Comment: ok you are right. I have empty line before <?php tag, and now i don't have this errors on the output, but session is still unsseted for some weird reason, i will look in the code further now and i came back if i didn't find solution for that problem, but this problems with errors are solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already...` a typical error when something is before session_start()

You need to write `session_start()` above headers(). As error says you already sent something beforee session start. Make Session start the very first line of your script, and leave no spaces before `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

use ob_start(); on top of the php page

Comment: thank you, but i already solved this problem.Reason for that errors in my case is empty line before <?php tag. Very stupid thing at all.

Comment: sorry, i will see to it. thank you for your polite advise.